# Queue copy constructor

Tags: java, linked-list, queue, copy-constructor

I'm not sure if there is something wrong with my copy constructor for my queue (DSQueue) or if there is another reason for my problem. The copy constructor seems to copy the contents fine but if I try to **manipulate** the queue that was copied, the program fails. I've done some testing in my Queue's main method (see below) and I've run through a debugger. The IDE points out a NullPointerException when I try to change a queue in the line `testQ.list.add(new Token(1));` in my main method. This line gets the token fine but it doesn't begin the `add` method. Not sure why...

```
public class DSQueue extends Queue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DSQueue testQ = new DSQueue();

        System.out.println("Size of testQueue: " + testQ.theQueue.size());
        testQ.offer(new Token(100));
        testQ.offer(new Token(200));
        System.out.println("Size of testQueue after adding: " + testQ.theQueue.size());

        System.out.println("\ntestQueue: " + testQ);

        // TETING COPY CONSTRUCTOR
        DSQueue newQ = new DSQueue(testQ);
        System.out.println("New queue (should be the same as testQueue): " + newQ + " - size: " + newQ.size());

        System.out.println("\nAfter changing one queue...");
        testQ.list.add(new Token(1));

        System.out.println("testQ: " + testQ + " - size: " + testQ.size());
        System.out.println("New queue: " + newQ + " - size: " + newQ.size());
    }

    // The list containing the data
    private DSList theQueue;

    public DSQueue() {
    theQueue = new DSList();
    }

    public DSQueue(Queue s) {
        this();

        // Cast s to a DSQueue type
        DSQueue sCasted = (DSQueue)s;

        // Create a reference for the Queue to be copied
        Node queueToCopy = sCasted.theQueue.head;

        while(queueToCopy != null) {
            this.offer(queueToCopy.getToken());
            queueToCopy = queueToCopy.next;
        }
    }
}

public abstract class Queue {

    public DSList list;

    public abstract boolean offer(Token t);


    public abstract Token poll();

    public abstract Token peek();

    @Override
    public abstract String toString();

    public abstract int size();

    public abstract boolean isEmpty();
}

public class DSList implements List {

    public Node head;

    public DSList() {
        head = null;
    }

    public DSList(Node head_) {
        head = head_;
    }

    // Copy constructor.
    public DSList(DSList other) {       

        // Create a reference for the list to be copied
        Node oldListNode = other.head;  

        while (oldListNode != null) {
            this.add(oldListNode.getToken());
            oldListNode = oldListNode.next;
        }       
    }

    /**
     * Appends the specified element to the end of this list.
     * @param obj The object to add. 
     * @return True if the object has been added to the list. 
     * 
     * @throws NullPointerException if the specified object is null.
     */
    public boolean add(Token obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        // If list is empty, add new node to front.
        if(isEmpty()) {  
            // Create a new Node. Add Token obj as data
            Node newNode = new Node(null, null, obj);  
            // point head to new Node, newNode
            head = newNode;
            return true;
        } else { 
            // create a reference of the start position in the list
            Node current = head;
            // While there are nodes remaining in the list, advance through to reach the end.
            while (current.next != null) 
                current = current.next;
            // Create a new node and append it to the end of the list, with 'prev' pointing to current (2nd to last node)
            Node newNode = new Node(null, current, obj);
            // Point old last element to the newest, last node in the list (in next variable)
            current.next = newNode;
            // Return true if successful addition of node.
            return true;
        }
    }
}

public class Token {

    public enum Type { OPERATOR, OPERAND, PAREN };
    public Type type;

    private String operator;
    private double operand;

    public Token(double result) {
        this.operand = result;
        this.type = Type.OPERAND;
    }
}

public class Node {

    public Node next;
    public Node prev;

    // data being stored in each node
    private Token t;

    // Node constructor
    public Node(Node next, Node prev, Token token) {
        this.next = next;
        this.prev = prev;
        this.t = token;
    }

    public Token getToken() {
        return t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Copy/paste from the console

Comment: Size of testQueue: 0  
Size of testQueue after adding: 2  

testQueue: 100.0 200.0
New queue (should be the same as testQueue): 100.0 200.0 - size: 2

After changing one queue...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ds.students.DSQueue.main(DSQueue.java:29)